# How do a UIScrollView in a Pop Up?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` as a pop up, which becomes visible when I click a button.The pop up has the dimensions `300x380`. In this `view` there are `labels` (headline) and a `button` ("Done"), between the `label` and the `button` I want to place a `UIScrollView`. I try to add a `UIScrollView` over the `storyboard`, but it won't work. The `ScrollView` doesn't scroll. Can anyone help me, how I can add a `ScrollView` in a pop up?
This is how my pop up are animated in and out:

```
func animateIn(){
    self.view.addSubview(bbsInfoView)
    bbsInfoView.center = self.view.center

    bbsInfoView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    bbsInfoView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        //self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
        self.bbsInfoView.alpha = 1
        self.bbsInfoView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }

}

func animateOut () {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.bbsInfoView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.bbsInfoView.alpha = 0

        // self.visualEffectView.effect = nil

    }) { (success:Bool) in
        self.bbsInfoView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

And there is my pop up in the `storyboard`:
[image: Pop up view]

Answer (score 0):

The scrollview contentSize should be equal or greater than the dimensions of the childviews on it. if you want to scroll scrollview vertically, its content height should be increased

Suppose you create a scroll view of dimension 300 x 200
it contains labels vertically, each of height 20. The number of labels is 10. Then total height child views (labels) is 200. then it does not need to scroll. but if the number of labels is 30, then total height of child views is 300 where as the height of scroll view is only 200. In this case some labels will be hidden and scroll view does not scrolls.

Now, if you set the scroll view content size programatically,

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 310)];
```

Hope, you understand what changes need to apply in you code.